# How Heroku or Rails config a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am new to Rails.  I pushed my toy app from cloud9 to Heroku and magically my Heroku app is using a PostgreSQL even though my database.yml from the Heroku toolbelt for my app at Heroku is as follows:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I know it's using a PostgreSQL because I can remotely access the DB using pgAdmin III.

So what's happening inside Heroku?

Comment: dreamfly, have you found the solution or do you still have problems?

Comment: Now I know why.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Heroku, the Heroku server will inject its own database yml file (That will use database url).
This is why the database.yml in your code will have no effect.

You can read more here
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior

Answer (score 1):

Heroku does not allow the use of SQLite. It will use PostgreSQL and will automatically creates one for you when you upload your app.

SQLite is not really made to be a production database. Since SQLite runs in memory, if you used it as a database on Heroku your entire database would be cleared once per day. There is more information [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).

I am actually surprised you did not get any errors when deploying. In the past when I had accidentally left SQLite on, I always got a "push failed". 
Heroku has a really good [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) for changing your database from SQLite to PostgreSQL.